# Hyper-V: Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Video Device

Tags: windows-xp, video, virtual-machine, hyper-v, display-driver

Hyper-V uses the Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Video Device as your default video driver. This is okay, but the only issue that I have with it is that the color setting is 16 bit and not 32 bit. I need 32 bit for Google Sketchup 8. The VM OS is Windows XP SP3. Is there a way beside this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/90964f00-4e18-4f72-93ca-e9598508048f/16-bit-color-depth-limit-on-vms-how-can-i-modify-the-4meg-vram-limit-on-the-emulated-video-card) here to do this? I really don't want to mess with the registry.

Also I understand that RDP will use 32 bit color and just about any resolution I want. However Sketchup still flags an warning for using the 16 bit color setting.

Comment: SuperUsers aren't afraid of editing the registry. :)

Comment: @techie007 Not afraid, just would like it to be a last resort.

Comment: @techie007 How do I change the video adapter to use a "Standard VGA" driver? I don't see that option under display adapters in device manager.

Answer (score 2):

- Go into the VM and into XP's Device Manager.
- Changed video adapter to use the "Standard VGA" driver.
- Set colour depth to 32-bit.

The Standard VGA driver will be slower (no hardware acceleration) but it lets you get to 32-bit color depths.

That's essentially all the scripting at the link you provided does.

Comment: How do I change the video adapter to use a "Standard VGA" driver? I don't see that option under display adapters in device manager.